# WildFly server not starting (with and without project)

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I installed `jboss wildfly` just now but I'm having trouble to start it. With my project and without it, when I start, it shows in `console` the same error:

> 14:15:37,571 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version
>   1.5.2.Final 14:15:37,757 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final 14:15:37,829 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service
>   thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core
>   2.2.0.Final) starting 14:15:38,546 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot:
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException:
>   WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration    at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
>     at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:357)   at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Received non-all-whitespace
>   CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag().  at [row,col
>   {unknown-source}]: [417,0]    at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:614)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:487)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:472)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1174)
>     at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.nextElement(ParseUtils.java:55)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.nextElement(ParseUtils.java:71)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:255)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:141)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:103)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49)
>     at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
>     at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
>     ... 3 more
>
> 14:15:38,548 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner;
>   exiting. See previous messages for details. 14:15:38,560 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full
>   10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) stopped in 6ms

I already tried to find the reason of

> Received non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag()

but I didn't find something that could help me.

I have no idea why is this happening, I would be glad if someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled my `WildFly` and it started.

Answer (score 4):

> WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration

One of your configuration files does not respect its XSD, most probably `standalone*.xml` or `domain*.xml`.

> Received non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag()

There must be content in a tag where there shouldn't be.

> at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [417,0]

I would first check at line 417 of what I guess is your `domain*.xml`, although I'm not sure the line number will correspond.

Comment: I saw these xml just like you said, but I didnt find anything wrong, so I reinstalled my wildfly and it started. Thanks.

Comment: @mhery if it happens again, you should check the `*_xml_history` folders in your configuration directory : it contains previous versions of your configuration, which you could have used to restore your server to a previous working state.

Comment: great! this can be really usefull for the next errors i can have :)

Comment: in my case, i copied the configurations somewhere else and there are non-whitespace invisible characters. I deleted those and it worked.

Comment: @StevenFerrer Did you copy the conf from a windows machine or edit it on one? They might use `\r\n` line terminators which might not be parsed correctly on linux, that would indeed explain the error, and could be fixed with `dos2unix` if available or `tr -d $'\r'` otherwise

Comment: @Aaron, I was trying to configure Keycloak (which uses wildfly) following [this](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#database-configuration) guide and copied the configurations there. I was using Sublime Text and it didn't displayed these characters.

Comment: In my case, there was an incorrect character placed at the location and it got identified from the similar error mentioned above ```at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [417,0]```